# How to bundle Web App Manifest and favicons with webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, favicon, manifest.json

Is there a way how to bundle Web App Manifest (manifest.json) and favicons with webpack?

I'm using React. Until now, I included all my favicons, including manifest.json, directly in index.html in public folder (so it didn't go through webpack). However, I needed to dynamically load favicons and so I decided to move the code and favicon images into React application and inject the tags dynamically. But I don't know how to deal with manifest.json because there are paths to favicons and the favicons when included in React app and bundled with webpack have random hashed names.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add directly in your webpack configuration

```
plugins: [
 // ...
 new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
   favicon: 'admin/src/favicon.ico',
   inject: true, // Inject all files that are generated by webpack
 )}
],
```